# What does it mean that "I need a hole in the head"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I just read a paragraph nowhere on Internet:

> To paraphrase the indie band Cracker, what the world needs now is another programming language **like I need a hole in the head**. That said, Go has slowly but surely [...].

OK, I think I don't want a hole in the head, so what does it mean?

Comment: A hole in the head would be inconvenient, if not worse. Your brains would get wet if it rained, for one thing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Your description reminded me of the drawings from [Jimmy](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B9%BE%E7%B1%B3)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We never say that we need a hole in the head - the saying is always as you quoted:

> "*I need [x] **like** I need a hole in the head*".

I've emboldened the word 'like' to indicate that this is a *simile*. It compares the need for something to the need for a hole in the head. Who needs a hole in the head? Nobody. So, it means that you don't need [x] at all.

Apparently it is a translation of a Yiddish saying:

> “Ich darf es vi a loch in kop” (I need it like a hole in the head). Source: theidioms.com

Comment: The version of this expression I hear most commonly is "I need [x] like I need __another__ hole in my head." We all have pre-made holes in our heads for ears, eyes, nose and mouth. It is the extraneous hole that is not needed or desired.

Comment: @RobJarvis That is funny, but it is not true.